# Can't change displays refresh rate

Tags: macos, display

I'm using OS X 10.8.3 and I want to change the refresh rate of my display, but I can't. When I go to `System Preferences-> Displays`, I have two options for resolution: `Best for Display` and `Scaled`. The first one is default. A little bit lower, I see the `Refresh Rate` option at `60 Hertz`. When I click it, I can see there is also a `75 Hertz` item there, but it's greyed out and unavailable. If I change `Resolution` to `Scaled`, then I'm presented with a list of resolutions I can pick. For some resolutions, `75 Hertz` is available, but then another problem arises - the entire screen becomes stretched, so there's no point of using `75 Hertz` with it.

How do I change the refresh rate without stretching the screen from a Mac Mini MD387 and display LG E2242T?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using, both as computer and as display?

Comment: Mac Mini MD387 and display LG E2242T

Answer (score 2):

To use that refresh rate you would have to lower the resolution to a maximum of 1280x1024. See the [manual](http://www.lg.com/lgecs.downloadFile.ldwf?DOC_ID=KROWM000346264&ORIGINAL_NAME_b1_a1=ENG__SAC35293910__E42S_T.PDF&FILE_NAME=KROWM000346264.pdf&TC=DwnCmd), page 29.

Comment: but the screen becomes stretched if i pick this resolution or lower or any resolution else except 1344x1008

Comment: What are you using to connect to the mini? HDMI?